# Program skips to end after first input

Tags: c++, input, structure

hey guys so I have a pizza program that gathers weight name and size using a structure and allocates the memory dynamically. My problem comes after the user inputs a number for the diameter. My code looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  struct pizza
  {
    char name[15];
    float diameter;
    int weight;
  };
  pizza *user= new pizza{};

  cout << "Hello please enter some information about your pizza" << endl;
  cout << endl << "Diameter: ";

  cin >> user->diameter;
  cout << "company name: ";
  cin.get(user->name,15);
  cout << endl << "Weight: ";
  cin >> user->weight;

  cout << "here is the information that we have assembled about your pizza company" << endl;
  cout << "Company name: "<< user->name <<e ndl;
  cout << "diameter: " << user->diameter << endl;
  cout << "weight: " << user->weight << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

when I run the program it looks like this
Hello please enter some information about your pizza

Diameter: 40
company name:
Weight: here is the information that we have assembled about your pizza company
Company name:
diameter: 40
weight: 0

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: When I run the program it looks like this:                                             
Hello please enter some information about your pizza

Diameter: 40
company name:
Weight: here is the information that we have assembled about your pizza company
Company name:
diameter: 40
weight: 0

Comment: @Ddecky What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: Instead of moving to the next input, it simply skips to the end of the program

Comment: I use codeblocks as my IDE and it did give me a warning saying "extended initializer only available with -std = c++11 or -std=gnu++11" but besides that I encounter 0 errors

Comment: If you indent your code it will be easier to follow and find bugs.

Comment: Change `cin.get(user->name,15);` to `cin >> user->name;`, `cin.get()`  extracts characters from the stream, as unformatted input, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630513/difference-between-cin-and-cin-get-for-char-array), also rather than `endl`, I would use `\n` as the escape character. `endl` flushes the stream.

Answer (score 0):

what appears is that you haven't used the code for clearing the buffer.

**What is buffer?**

Temporary storage area is called buffer. All standard input and output devices contain input and output buffer. In standard C/C++, streams are buffered, for example in case of standard input,when we press the key on keyboard,it isn’t send to your program, rather it is buffered by operating system till the time is allotted to the program.

**How does it effect Programming?**
On various occasions you may need to clear the unwanted buffer so as to get the next input in the desired container and not in the buffer of previous variable.

```
cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);
```

This is the code you need to add in your program.

```
int main()
{
struct pizza
{
 char name[15];
 float diameter;
 int weight;

 };

 pizza*user= new pizza{
 };
 cout<<"Hello please enter some information about your pizza"<<endl;
 cout<<endl<<"Diameter: ";

 cin>>user->diameter;
 cout<<"company name: ";
 cin.clear();    //for clearing the input buffer
fflush(stdin);

cin.get(user->name,15);

cout<<endl<<"Weight: ";
cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);

cin>>user->weight;

cout<<"here is the information that we have assembled about your pizza 
company"<<endl;
cout<<"Company name: "<<user->name<<endl;
cout<<"diameter: " <<user->diameter<<endl;
cout<<"weight: "<<user->weight<<endl;
return 0;



}
```

after encountering“cin” statement, we require to input a character array or a string , we require to clear the input buffer or else the desired input is occupied by buffer of previous variable, not by the desired container.On pressing “Enter” (carriage return) on output screen after the first input , as the buffer of previous variable was the space for new container(as we did’nt clear it) , the program skips the following input of container.